# Long text entries not inserting into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a form with just 2 user-editable fields. One is a text field to enter an numerical `ID`, the other uses tinyMCE to input lengthy amounts of text to be saved into MySQL on submission:

```
if ( !empty ( $_POST ) ) {
    $location_id = $_POST['restaurant_id'];
    $content = $_POST['content'];
    $query = "INSERT INTO restaurant_reviews 
              (location_id, text1, review_date) 
              VALUES
              ('$location_id', '$content', NOW())";
    $execute = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
    print_r($_POST);
}
```

The issue is that when even fairly small amounts of text are submitted in the form (by small amounts I mean a max of 2/3 normal paragraphs) the record is not generated in MySQL. The form submits successfully every time with a few words of text in the tinyMCE field.

Irrespective of the amount of text submitted in the form, it all appears in the post array when it's echoed out by the print_r function, it just doesn't get as far as the DB. The text1 column is type longtext so sure this isn't the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: What would you expect to happen if there were any quote characters in the posted content?

Comment: Your code is wide open to sql injections! Please read about the benefits of prepared statements and how they can help to fix that.

Comment: Your code doesnt escape the input so any single quotes will break the query

Comment: Can u provide us with sample $_POST['content']

Comment: Thanks, seems to be working fine after escaping the text field.

Comment: Use `bind_param()` instead of string substitution, then you don't have to escape anything.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar have just tried this and makes the code even simpler.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("database_host", "username", "password", "database_name");

$id         = (int)mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['restaurant_id']);
$content    = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['content']);
```

to escape characters that may interfere with the SQL statement

Comment: Even better would be to recommend using bind variables